# How do I access a custom field from an action?

Tags: entities, 8, rules

I want to access a custom field names field_heat in a Rules action in D8 and it does not accept it. This is my condition:
[image]

And this is my action which cannot be accepted:
[image]

If I use a build field like node.title.value it works OK so the problem must be with custom fields. I am using Rules 8.x-3.0-alpha1.

Comment: In D7 you could use a condition of "entity has field" or something like that to bring fields into scope that were otherwise missing. Do you have the same option?

Comment: The option is there but I haven't managed to come up with a working configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preface

Be aware of what's written in [comment nr 7 of issue nr 2574691](https://www.drupal.org/node/2574691#comment-10944181):

> [rules 8.x-3.0-alpha1](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/releases/8.x-3.0-alpha1) ... is a **preview release** and is **not intended for production sites**. Use at your own risk.

With that in mind, read on for more details to do a similar experiment with [rules 8.x-3.0-alfa1](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/releases/8.x-3.0-alpha1).

## Verify setup of content type and field

- I'll use content type "Article", which already has a field with machine name "`field_image`" (out of the D8-box).
- Navigate to `/admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields` to verify this.

## Create a rule

- Enable the Rules module.
- Navigate to `/admin/config/workflow/rules` and create a new rule, with these details:

  - Use **Rules Event** "Before saving content"
  - Add a **Rules Condition** like "Entity has field" (for the `field_image` field). To do so, click on "Value" (within the "Entity" box), and select `node`. And also click on "Value" (within the "Field" box), and select `field_image`. Then click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button (to save the Rules Condition).
  - Add a **Rules Action** "Set a data value",and continue like so: click on "Value" (within the "Data" box), and select `node:field_image:value` (note that for this Data Selector I'm using `:` (twice), instead of `.` (twice) as in your screenprint). And also enter some "Value" (within the "Value" box), eg `myNiceImage`. Then click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button (to save the Rules Action).
  - You are then returned to the "edit rules reaction" screen (for the rule you are editing. And it shows a message like "*You have unsaved changes.*". Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button (to save the rule). Then a message will be shown like "Reaction rule ABC has been updated." (ABC = the label you gave to your rule).

## Verify if the rule got saved

- Navigate to `/admin/config/workflow/rules` to ensure the rule was really saved (that it does show up there).
- Navigate to `admin/config/development/configuration/single/export` and as "Configuration type" select "Reaction Rule". Then select the label of your rule as the "Configuration name".
- You should then see the exported rule, which should look similar to mine, i.e.:

  ```
  uuid: ab289332-0b45-484f-a1ae-38842620b7e4
  langcode: en
  status: true
  dependencies: {  }
  id: check_a_field_before_saving_a_node
  label: 'Check a field before saving a node'
  events:
    -
      event_name: 'rules_entity_presave:node'
  description: ''
  tags:
    - ''
  config_version: '3'
  expression:
    id: rules_rule
    uuid: 354332c5-8307-4097-b33c-0e77307a5e0e
    conditions:
      id: rules_and
      uuid: e82407a4-05c6-45d3-8195-1c1b5f34a07d
      conditions:
        -
          id: rules_condition
          uuid: 3c9094ed-95ec-4202-8398-5a6ca000604a
          context_values:
            entity: node
            field: field_image
          context_mapping: {  }
          context_processors: {  }
          provides_mapping: {  }
          condition_id: rules_entity_has_field
          negate: false
    actions:
      id: rules_action_set
      uuid: 3313095c-f75a-46f2-8d11-f845d12a90f2
      actions:
        -
          id: rules_action
          uuid: 23a3a68e-893e-48c4-a7ee-102201af5a25
          context_values:
            data: 'node:field_image:value'
            value: myNiceImage
          context_mapping: {  }
          context_processors: {  }
          provides_mapping: {  }
          action_id: rules_data_set
  ```
- The above export should illustrate that I could perfectly save this ... because otherwise I could not have exported it, right?

## Pushing the limits

So far so good, but next I wanted to **update** the value to be assigned in my Rules Action, let's say `myNiceImage` should be updated to `myNewestNiceImage`. So I returned to my Rules Action, and started to edit it. But, that resulted in an error message like so:

> The context Data may only be configured using a selector.

By clicking on the <kbd>Switch to data selection</kbd> button (so that the button label changed to <kbd>Swith to direct input mode</kbd>), and trying again, I got another error message like so:

> Data selector node:field_image for context Data is invalid. Unable to get variable node:field_image, it is not defined.

## There has to be a way to do it ...

So it seems like updating a Rules Action is not what you should try to do (at least not in the current D8 release of the Rules module).

However, here are the steps I performed to actually get the value updated (from `myNiceImage` to `myNewestNiceImage`) anyhow:

- delete the Rules Action (with the old value `myNiceImage`).
- create a new Rules Action (with the new value `myNewestNiceImage`).

Voilà!

PS: did you notice I'm using "***Entity has field***", and not "***Entity is of type***"?

Comment: I have a hard time replicating. Can you share some screenshots or more detailed settings?

Comment: I cannot create the \entity has field' condition. Trying to use 'node:field_image:value' I get an error message 'Data selector node:field_image:value for context Field is invalid. Unable to get variable node:field_image:value, it is not defined.'

Note that I have entered 'node' as entity data selector.

Comment: @FotisDimanidis : your turn again ... see my updated answer ...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I replicated your steps, basically doing the same thing that I always did, but I ended up with a WSOD and error: Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\rules\Plugin\Condition\EntityHasField::doEvaluate() must implement interface Drupal\Core\Entity\FieldableEntityInterface, string given in Drupal\rules\Plugin\Condition\EntityHasField->doEvaluate() (line 47 of /home/drlz1/www/sites/default/modules/rules/src/Plugin/Condition/EntityHasField.php).

I have double-checked by testing on http://simplytest.me as well. Which Drupal version are you using?

Comment: @FotisDimanidis : I used the "latest and greatest D8 version, ie alfa1" (there is no more mature version). You didn't specify what you did prior to getting that WSOD. But as per your "*I replicated your steps*" I assume that WSOD occured when trying to execute the rule afterwards. In that case, I'd suggest you create a followup question (maybe with a reference to this question). And also mark this answer as accepted?

Comment: Yes when saving the article you get this error. It's pretty easy to replicate. Actually I was asking which Drupal core version are you using.

Marking you answer as the right one as I believe it should work if Rules wanted to cooperate. Thank you.

Comment: @FotisDimanidis : merci for the accept! FYI : The Drupal (core) version I used was pretty sure the same as yours ... since I also did an experiment on simplytest.me ... (so whatever the core version was the day I did my experiment). And because of your last comment (= you get this error when saving), I think you should create an issue for that on D.O (if no such issue exist yet).

Comment: Issue here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2776109

Answer (score 1):

Looks like to get access to a Content Type fields the condition needed is 'Entity is of bundle' [as stated in this issue comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/2912457#comment-12623871), and fill it with:

- **Entity:** node
- **Type:** node
- **Bundle:** Your content type machine name

Answer (score 0):

I have received the same error. What I have done is:

1. Go to configuration sync (Configuration > development > configuration synchronisation)
2. Export single item: Reaction rule > YOUR RULE. Copy the generated text.
3. Delete the previous rules you have built
4. Import single item: Reaction rule > Paste the generated text. This time, change the value of the field by hand, that the rule was not accepting previously.
5. If you constructed the structe correctly, the rule works.